# I unplugged an SD card without clicking eject, and now everything is read only

Tags: nautilus, sd-card

Title. It's a 64 gig SD and I don't have the space to back it up and format, but if I have to I will. I really don't want to though.

Answer (score 0):

If the data are very valuable, it is a good idea to clone the drive to another drive of at least the same size, and do the repair work on that drive. You can clone the drive (in this case the SD card) with mkusb, which helps you write to the correct drive (instead of overwriting valuable data on some other drive).

Or in your case with a read-only drive - Please back it up! Maybe it is 'gridlocked'. In that case the next stage is that it will be completely dead.

---

Try to repair the file system. If there is a Microsoft file system, FAT32 (standard) or NTFS, use Windows tools to repair it. If there is a linux file system, use linux tools.

If those tools do not work, try with Testdisk and PhotoRec. See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[Pendrive lifetime](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297), explaining 'gridlock'

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986), applies also to memory cards

[CGSecurity - Data recovery: TestDisk & PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/)

Comment: I yolo'd and ran fsck -v on it while unmounted without backing up the files. Luckily got it successfully.